# Enyo custom event is not handled and undefined in simple example

Tags: javascript, dom-events, enyo

I'm learning the events in Enyo js framework and can't understand why I get the error and event `onModelChanged` is not handled. Error message is:

> "Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function"

Code:

```js
debugger; 
enyo.kind({
    name : "MyModel",
    kind: "enyo.Model",
    defaultSource: "mocked",
    published: {
        title : "not set",
        text : "not set",       
    },
    
    events : {
        onModelChanged : "",
    },
    
    handlers: {
        onModelChanged : "modelLoadedHandler" 
    },
    
    modelLoadedHandler : function(inSender, inEvent){
        debugger;
        console.log("handler in model");
        console.log(inEvent.textMsg);
        return true;
    },
        
    fetch : function(opts){
        this.inherited(arguments);
        debugger;
        this.doModelChanged({textMsg: "fire event"}); // Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function
            
    }       
        
});



var model = new MyModel();
model.fetch();
```

P.S.  Leave this code as an answer not to be deleted by jsfiddle

```
enyo.kind({
    name: "MyMockSource",
    kind: "enyo.Source",
    fetch: function(model, opts) {
        if(model instanceof enyo.Model) {
            opts.success({title: "testing", text: "Some stuff"});
        } else {
            throw new Error("Model mock only");
        }
    }
});

new MyMockSource({name: "mocked"});

enyo.kind({
    name : "MyModel",
    kind: "enyo.Model",
    source: "mocked",
    attributes: {
        title : "not set",
        text : "not set",       
    },
    fetched: function(opts){
        this.inherited(arguments);
        enyo.log("fetched");
        // Do something here if you need to, otherwise you might want to overload
        // the parse method and set parse: true to modify the retrieved data
    },
    titleChanged: function(was, is) {
        enyo.log("Title is now: " + is);
    }
});

enyo.kind({
    name: "MyView",
    components: [
        {kind: "Button", content: "Fetch", ontap: "fetch"},
        {name: "title"},
        {name: "text"}
    ],
    bindings: [
        {from: "model.title", to: "$.title.content"},
        {from: "model.text", to: "$.text.content"}
    ],
    fetch: function() {
        this.set("model", new MyModel());    // Probably want to create model elsewhere
        this.model.on("change", enyo.bindSafely(this, "modelChanged"));
        this.model.fetch();
    },
    modelChanged: function() {
        this.log("Something happened to my model!");
    }
});

new enyo.Application({ name: "app", view: "MyView" });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`enyo.Model` is not an `enyo.Object` (much less an `enyo.Component`).  It does not support published properties or events.  You want to define `attributes` for a model.  You can still get notifications on property changes using the `propertyChanged` event or by using `observers`.

Also, you probably want to overload `fetched` if you want to know that fetching has completed. `fetch` possibly returns before the data has been fetched.

If you want to subscribe to events from outside then you probably want to bind to a specific property on the model or to the `changed` event using `model.on('change')` (note this is a different event system from the `events: []` system used elsewhere.

Update: Here's a fiddle showing the various ways to work with the model and binding to data

http://jsfiddle.net/RoySutton/5jo0p7ar/

Comment: Sorry, I'm new in JS and UI and didn't catch what you mean about outside events. But how to fix this code to make it work the way I expect?

Comment: I meant that if you wanted to catch events from the model from an object that wasn't the model itself.  Added working fiddle.

Answer (score 1):

When you use the event system in this way, you are typically expecting a component higher up the chain to handle the onModelChanged event, not the component that defines the event.  Further, enyo.Model is a special case and uses a different observer mechanism, I believe.  That's probably why you are getting "undefined" for the function call, because there is no magic mapping between onModelChanged to a doModelChanged method.